# Error: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:1.0. when adding google service plugin in build.gradle in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-signin

I am integrating OAuth login for Google+ on my android application, following the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).

According to the tutorial, I should add the Google Service plugin by adding
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.0'` dependency to top-level  `build.gradle`  in my android project.

However, when I sync the gradle with the changes, I see the error as follows:

> Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:1.0.
>
> Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/1.0/google-services-1.0.pom
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android  Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/1.0/google-services-1.0.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/1.0/google-services-1.0.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/1.0/google-services-1.0.jar

In my `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

It seems that the android studio is not able to find google-services plugin from repositories.

Does anybody have the same issue? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: It´s not "com.google.gms:google-services". But "com.google.gms.google-services" in that case.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today. In the samples they use this line instead:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'`

This works.

Comment: check that you have jcenter() on your repositories in the buildscript. It wasn\t working for me cause I was using mavenCentral() only

Comment: How can we find out when this is updated? e.g. to 1.3.0-final or 1.4.0?

Comment: As mentioned below checkout https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/ for the latest version.

Comment: Please check the available version at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/view . Please use available version instead provided in tutorial

Comment: It's better to import specific APIs, which in this case will be `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'`. It will not import unnecessary APIs of fitness, wearable, maps, etc. You can see the [table 1 on this page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: @Chiara Give me your address, so that I can send you a beer. You sure as hell deserve one.

Answer (score 50):

For me I had to switch the repository to `jcenter()`.  I was using mavenCentral and getting this error.  As soon as I switched to `jcenter()` it pulled the dependency down.

To do this, open your `build.gradle` and replace each instance of `mavenCentral()` with `jcenter()`

Answer (score 13):

Google updated [their guide](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app). Where it was classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.0' now reads classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1' like joluet suggested.

[image]

Comment: They seem to have changed it again.
It now simply states: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Answer (score 10):

Google now released the plugin v1.3.0

I was able to solve it using [this](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/):

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0'

Answer (score 10):

I resolved this issue by doing the following things:

1. In build.gradle (at project level):

   ```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

   buildscript {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
           classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
        }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
       }
   }
   ```
2. In build.gradle (at module level):

   On top added:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```

   and in dependecies added:

   ```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
   ```

Apart from this make sure you have updated the Google Play services and Google repository in the SDK.

Answer (score 7):

As of **25th Nov,2015**, google released a newer version.

Try adding:
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha1'`

And don't forget to add `jcenter()` repository under buildscript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you forgotten gradle's project level,

From [developers page](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating):

Add the dependency to your **project-level** build.gradle
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'`

Add the plugin to your **app-level** build.gradle:
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Answer (score 4):

Google has updated [GCM](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app#set-up-your-project) go check it and for that you have to update your Android Studio too.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you against doing what you are doing. I did it too (by following [Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#add-config) blindly) but ended up with exceeding 65K method limit.

So, you should remove the following lines from your gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.0'
```

Now import APIs of Google Plus with simple gradle import:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding **jcenter** repository to project level build.gradle helped in my case:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter();
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to setup firebase for my android app when I faced this problem. Following screenshot should clarify things -

[image]

Couple of things I would like to point out -
1. Once you

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This line should be at the bottom of the app level gradle file. Not sure why but putting at the top did not workout for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Android Studio, try to add google service with the IDE.

1. Right click on folder module.
2. On left list at `Developer Services` choose desired service.
3. Wait for syncing and the IDE will automatically add google dependecies.
4. add `classpath` on `buildscript`

   `buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
       }
   }`

Answer (score 0):

You maybe miss this step

*Copy the google-services.json file you just downloaded into the app/ or mobile/ directory of your Android Studio project. Open the Android Studio Terminal pane:
$ move path-to-download/google-services.json app/*

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I do not think Installing google-service plugin does have to do with google-service.json file at this time, as the json file will be loaded AFTER the plugin installed. In other words, I asked about the issue of installing google-service plugin, not loading the configuration file with the plugin. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem while following the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) for implementing a GCM client in Android Studio, however, the message I got was :

> Error: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1...

Although I never figured out what was wrong, I simply copied my sources, resources, manifest, and keystore into a new Android Studio project. I then edited the auto-generated gradle build files for the new project by manually re-adding my dependencies.

I made sure not to copy over my build files from the old project verbatim (since the source of the error likely lay in them somewhere).

It is not a satisfying solution, but it worked for me and it took little time.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add classpath '`com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1`' to `dependencies` of your `(Top level build file)` the `build.gradle` that has the `(Project:<name of your project)`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the current version as in the link below says, by now:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta4'
```

Check this answer:

[Update gradle version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30536935/4726250)

Answer (score 0):

We have to look for the last version in my case was:

```
dependencies {    
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
}
```

[Here](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/) you can find a list of the versions.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `.idea folder` exists a **workspace.xml** file that defines the `project's structure`. I suggest you to close Android Studio, then `delete .idea folder` and then import the project again. The .idea would be generated by the IDE again. For me this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding this under `dependencies` worked

```
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently updated to Android Studio 2.3 and somehow apply plugin doesn't work.

After that, I tried various ways and then what work is when I commented out app's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and then I add this to top-level build.gradle (below *classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'*):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and then it works.