# Android plugin 1.3 error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-sdk-tools

This is error I got when updated my SDK and Build tool to **Android M**

```
Android Build Tools
Found incompatible Build Tools and Android plugin versions:
* Module 'app' is using Android plugin 1.2.3 and Build Tools 23.0.0 rc1
Please use Android plugin 1.3 or newer, or an older Build Tools version.
Otherwise the project won't build.
```

when classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`
changed to **1.3**

I got another error.

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3/gradle-1.3.pom
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3/gradle-1.3.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3/gradle-1.3.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3/gradle-1.3.jar
```

What should I do now ?

Comment: did you read the error? change your plugin to 1.3 from 1.2.3

Comment: Thanks for quick response , but how to do that ? because I am new to Android Studio @tyczj

Comment: Try `1.3.0` instead of `1.3`.

Comment: @CommonsWare 1.3.0 doesn't work on my end.  I have to do 1.3.+

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: It is a beta, which is screwing up the normal pattern. AFAIK, the current edition is `1.3.0-beta1`, and using that (instead of `1.3.+`) works.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The was because at that time android gradle plugin 1.3 had not been released yet. It was in beta.

So, try setting the version to `1.3.0-beta1`.

You can see the list of all the android grade plugin versions [here](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/). Pro tip: scroll all the way down to the bottom so it's easier to see the latest version. :)

**Update**

Android gradle plugin 1.3 is finally released: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3.0/

Answer (score 22):

**Update**

version 1.4.0-beta1 is now available

---

Version 1.3.0 of the android gradle plugin is not released yet.

The current latest version (to use with Android-Studio 1.3-preview) is 1.3.0-beta1.

Put this in your root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
     ...
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1'
         ...
     }
}
```

You can find the latest published version of the plugin on this page: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

Note that you may also need to update your build tools :

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc1"
    ...
}
```

This version of the build tools is available with the sdk manager under section "Tools (preview channel)"

Comment: Thanks to you @ben75, As you have explained more on it.

Comment: buildToolsVersion "23.0.0_rc1" doesn't work for me, but buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc1" does (using a space instead of an underscore)

Answer (score 1):

As Android Studio was just officially updated to 1.3 (Gradle as well).

changing gradle version from 1.2.3 to 1.3.+ in build.gradle file worked for me.
It should now look like this:

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the previous answers above didn't work in my case. Gradle simply freezes while resolving dependencies (I can't find 1.3.0-beta1 in the repo either for manual download):

[image]

I had to downgrade the buildToolsVersion from "23.0.0 rc1" to "22.0.1" in the build.gradle (Module: app) and it worked fine afterwards.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
...
```