# Can't build project for google app invites

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying this Google app invites thing but i cant get it to work.

I followed the steps just like https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app suggested but i soon encountered the problem of not finding 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.0' and so i followed [Error: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:1.0. when adding google service plugin in build.gradle in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527369/error-could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services1-0-when-adding-google-ser) and gradle continued to build but then i encounted this error:

[image]

i followed this answer: [Android Studio: failed to complete gradle execution, cause is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407855/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-cause-is-empty) and even tried with the option -Xmx512m but the problem persists... Anyone with similar issue trying to build put app invites in their app and not be able to even build the project?

**Edit:** I didn't manage to solve the issue, but i did manage to get app invites to work. I didn't need to do these steps from the App Invites google guide:

> Add the dependency to your project's top-level build.gradle: classpath
>   'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1' Add the plugin to your
>   app-level build.gradle: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

And like so, gradle wouldn't fail to complete because i only needed to add the google play services dependency to the app level build.gradle file.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: I didn't exactly solve the issue. I just did not add the google-services:1.3.0-beta1 and the plugin so the error didn't occur and the google app invites still managed to work!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by not including the entire play-services. Instead of:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'

type this:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.5.+'

By the way, you said you solved your problem by not using the google-service plugin. Have you checked you are able to send invitations? If the plugin does not load the configuration file how does it work?

Comment: I use many other services from the play-services so i figured i just include the whole bundle.

I have the configuration file setup and in the correct place. And yes, i'm able to send invitations and i'm also receiving them.

I guess maybe including the dependecy is enough?

Comment: If you can avoid to include the whole bundle it's better.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1`. That's what works with the [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/appinvites/build.gradle).

Comment: I did (as i pointed in the first link) and that originated the problem on the image.

Comment: Aah, sorry, missed that. Does cleaning and rebuilding the project change anything?

Comment: No, problem persisted. Also restarted android studio and rebooted, still fails to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your repositories in your build.gradle file.  It seems the dependency is on jcenter and not mavencentral.  Replace mavenCentral() with jcenter().  This worked for me.