# How do i keep different configurations for my android app with GCM 3.0

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I want to keep different configurations for my debug/release build variants but apparently, the google-services.json file only allows for one. Is there any alternative? Is there a way to keep several files?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31895658/3014036

Answer (score 18):

I'm using this workaround to solve a similar issue with build flavours.

The flavour specific *google-service.json* files are stored under */app/src/{flavour-name}/google-service.json*. To copy this to the */app* dir the following code may be added to the */app/build.gradle* file:

```
    gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task task ->
        if(task.name ==~ /process.*GoogleServices/) {
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                if(task.name ==~ /(?i)process${variant.name}GoogleServices/){ 
                    copy {
                        from "/src/${variant.flavorName}"
                        into '.'
                        include 'google-services.json'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the absence of flavours (as I understand your question) the following */app/build.gradle* code snippet did the job in an android studio test project:

```
    gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task task ->
        if(task.name ==~ /process.*GoogleServices/) {
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                if(task.name ==~ /(?i)process${variant.name}GoogleServices/){
                    copy {
                        from '.'
                        into '.'
                        rename { String fileName ->
                            fileName.replace("google-services-${variant.name}.json", 'google-services.json')
                        }
                        include "google-services-${variant.name}.json"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The snippet expects a *google-services-debug.json* and a *google-services-release.json* in your */app* dir and copies and renames it to *google-services.json*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this will run for all the variants each time. Right ? didn't try it but tried stuff like that.

Comment: I needed to remove the first / before src
`from "src/${variant.flavorName}"` but otherwise @MartinS your solution is just plain awesome.

Comment: it should be from "src/${variant.flavorName}", not from "/src/${variant.flavorName}". Please verify

Comment: I can confirm that the first / must be removed. For me, it worked properly with Gradle 1.3.1 and Play Services plugin 1.3.1, but when updating both to 1.5.0, the following error was shown: `File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it`

Comment: @AndroidGecko Yes, it works if you remove the first slash: `from "/src/${variant.flavorName}"` becomes `from "src/${variant.flavorName}"`

Comment: Do we need to add a different project in firebase for each variant to get google-services.json file.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to define build specific configs at this point. Good idea though, seems like something useful.