# Switch GCM Client on Development and Production

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, push

Just implement the new GCM. For official document,

> Copy the google-services.json file you just downloaded into the app/ or mobile/ directory of your Android Studio project.

Anyone know how to setup gradle to switch development and production to use different google-services.json?

Comment: possible duplicate of [google-services.json for different productFlavors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31895542/3014036) for different `productFlavors`.

In your case it's debug/production. I don't know why you need to switch between production and debug but i think you can do the same as what I proposed for flavors.

Create two extra folders `src/release` and `src/debug` , in each of the folders you put the corresponding `google-services.json` , so you will have: `src/release/google-services.json` and `src/debug/google-services.json`

Now in gradle add this :

```
android {

// set build config here to get the right gcm configuration.
//def myBuildConfig = "release"
def myBuildConfig = "debug"

// this will copy the right google-services.json file to app/ directory.
if (myBuildConfig.equals("release")) {
    println "--> release copy!"
    copy {
        from 'src/release/'
        include '*.json'
        into '.'
    }
} else {
    println "--> debug copy!"
    copy {
        from 'src/debug/'
        include '*.json'
        into '.'
    }
}

// other stuff
}
```