# Android push notifications with GCM and different product flavors

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-productflavors

I have an Android app containing 10 different app flavors, and I need to send push notifications targeting specific flavors. I got it working with one, by using google official support documentation - using the file google-services.json on the root of my project.
I know I will need one google-services.json file per each of the flavors (since they're in fact different apps), but the issue comes on where to put those different files, since this needs to go to the root of the project and not to the root of each specific flavor.
Anyone has had a similar issue before and found a way of handling it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31895658/3014036