# Differentiate between productFlavors in Android app.gradle file during build process

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build-process, build.gradle

```
    android {
    final String analyticsJSON = "lite"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ralok.apps"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    productFlavors {
        findlostandroidphone {
            versionCode 1
            versionName 'v1.0'
            applicationId 'com.ralok.apps.findlostandroidphone'
        }
        findlostandroidphonepro {
            versionCode 1
            versionName 'v1.0'
            applicationId 'com.ralok.apps.findlostandroidphonepro'
        }
        if (analyticsJSON.equals("lite")) {
            println "--> FLPLite JSON copied!"
            copy {
                from 'src/findlostandroidphone/'
                include 'google-services.json'
                into '.'
            }
        } else {
            println "--> FLPPro JSON copied!"
            copy {
                from 'src/findlostandroidphonepro/'
                include 'google-services.json'
                into '.'
            }
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        lite_release {
            keyAlias 'ASDFGHJKL'
            keyPassword 'ASDFGHJKL'
            storeFile file('ASDFGHJKL.jks')
            storePassword 'ASDFGHJKL'
        }
        pro_release {
            keyAlias 'POIUYTREWQ'
            keyPassword 'POIUYTREWQ'
            storeFile file('POIUYTREWQ.jks')
            storePassword 'POIUYTREWQ'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I have to manually change the final String analyticsJSON = "***lite/pro***" so that the if loop copies the right json file to the root directory. Is there anyway I can automate this and always have the correct productFlavour in analyticsJSON String instead of me changing the value manually every time I switch between productFlavors. My groovy is bad and I have tried but failed to achieve this.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697154/gradle-android-plugin-add-custom-flavor-attribute help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally a solution for handling different flavors is implemented in version com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54

Another alternative solution is on

[How do i keep different configurations for my android app with GCM 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901610/how-do-i-keep-different-configurations-for-my-android-app-with-gcm-3-0/30965053#)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to differentiate the build system will do it for you.  Simply place the files in the correct path per build flavor.  For example.

For `findlostandroidphone` place your `google-services.json` in the following location.

`src/findlostandroidphone/google-services.json` the build the file will be copied into the final location automatically for that product flavor.  Same for the `pro` version.

What you have right now will be executed in the configuration phase. which probably works... for a single build type.  If you want to build both types at the same time then you should move the files and remove the `final String analyticsJSON = "lite"` entirely.  Then during the execution phase gradle will copy the file and execute the build with the correct file for that `productFlavor`.

Comment: Without a conditional check, the latter seems to override the former copied file in the root folder of the project. I mean the first findlostandroidphone flavor copies the JSON file to the root folder and then the file is overwritten by findlostandroidphonepro flavor JSON file at the root. If I'm taking a build of findlostandroidphone then I still end up with findlostandroidphonepro JSON file. I need to have a conditional check here somehow. Don't know which variable will have that information for me to do a check on it.

Comment: If I put the respective JSON files in the different flavors then it copies the JSON file to the build but I need it in the root folder of the package. Which is why I have the below code written
copy {
                from 'src/findlostandroidphonepro/'
                include 'google-services.json'
                into '.'
            }