# Commiting google-services.json to GitHub

Tags: android, github, travis-ci, google-signin

I am creating a public android project and I am using Google Sign-In service. I am doing it according to [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating). As it says, I have got the google-services.json file.

- Do I need to commit the above file to Github?
- Do other developers (If someone contributes) need this file?
- Or, do they have to create there own?
- By the way I am using Travis-CI. Will this file affect to CI build?

Comment: It does look like a fairly essential file to me.

Comment: Yes, But do I need to commit that file to Github? Since its containing my google app id and stuff doesn't that means that other developers should also generate it for themselves?

Comment: If it contains *your* sensitive data and is needed by Travis to build it, you can [file encrypt](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files) it. If it doesn't contain sensitive data and is needed, add it. In all other cases ignore it. (I'd also look around if Android repos have it added and do the same)

Comment: Google is [not recommending](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more?authuser=0#config-files-objects) including google-services.json in  source control only for the open-source projects:
"For open source projects, we generally do not recommend including the app's Firebase config file or object in source control because, in most cases, your users should create their own Firebase projects and point their apps to their own Firebase resources (via their own Firebase config file or object)."

Answer (score 23):

You can create a new [build variant](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) and store a template `google-services.json` to be used for your build on your CI platform in your app [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/android-googlesignin/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L25-L28).

Use a different `google-services.json` for the new `dev` build variant (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors)). Add the following `google-services.json` template to `app/src/dev` [folder](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/android-googlesignin/blob/master/app/src/dev/google-services.json) :

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "",
    "project_id": ""
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:123456789012:android:1234567890123456",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.your.package"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "",
          "client_type": 3
        },
        {
          "client_id": "",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.your.package",
            "certificate_hash": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": ""
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "analytics_property": {
            "tracking_id": ""
          }
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Note that I have extended this google-services in case you also use Google Analytics or GCM service.

You would have the following configuration :

```
app/
├── src/
│   ├── main/
│   └── dev/
│       └── google-services.json
├── google-services.json
└── build.gradle
```

You can use either :

- a new build type
- a new product flavor (if you already have existing ones)

### Build Type

Add the following build type:

```
buildTypes {

    dev {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

We don't need to build this "dev" build variant in regular build, so you can exclude this variant if a parameter is not specified. Add the following to your app [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/android-googlesignin/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L32-L48) :

```
def build_param = "${build}";

if (build_param != "dev") {
    //exclude production build
    android.variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals('dev')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true);
        }
    }
} else {
    //exclude all except production build
    android.variantFilter { variant ->
        if (!variant.buildType.name.equals('dev')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true);
        }
    }
}
```

### Product flavor

Add the `dev` product flavor to existing ones :

```
productFlavors {

    full {
    }

    dev {
    }
}
```

To remove this `dev` product flavor from the regular build :

```
def build_param = "${build}";

if (build_param != "dev") {
    //exclude dev
    android.variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('dev')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true);
        }
    }
} else {
    //exclude all but dev
    android.variantFilter { variant ->
        if (!variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('dev')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Eventually, add your app module `google-services.json` to [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/android-googlesignin/blob/master/.gitignore#L7) :

```
app/google-services.json
```

We have previously ensured that this `dev` variant will only be used when parameter `build=dev` is specified

Edit [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/android-googlesignin/blob/master/.travis.yml#L26-L27) to modify the build config :

```
script:
  - ./gradlew clean build -Pbuild=dev
```

`-Pbuild=dev` will only build dev build variant using `google-services.json` located in `app/src/dev/google-services.json`

Take a look at [this sample project](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/android-googlesignin) which is using [google-services Google project](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin)

In [Travis log](https://travis-ci.org/bertrandmartel/android-googlesignin), you can see that the JSON file being parsed is the one for the `dev` build variant :

```
Parsing json file: /home/travis/build/bertrandmartel/android-googlesignin/app/src/dev/google-services.json
```

---

#### Extra Note

Note that this method is not limited to CI and can be extended for your production build when you require a production `google-services.json` or a different `AndroidManifest.xml` (with some specific properties like [fabric.io](https://get.fabric.io/) key)

Check [this method](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/044555230e4ea0bfc009782b90cbc01d) to prevent commitment of fabric keys embedded in AndroidManifest.xml (and can't be imported from gradle) that is using a different build variant and using a parameter to enable the production build.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `travis encrypt-file google-services.json`

[Documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/)

You can do it by:

- installed the Travis CI Command Line Client by running `$ gem install travis`.
- logged in to Travis CI using `$ travis login` or `$ travis login --pro`

  ```
  $ travis encrypt-file super_secret.txt
  encrypting super_secret.txt for rkh/travis-encrypt-file-example
  storing result as super_secret.txt.enc
  storing secure env variables for decryption
  ```

Then it will print on the console this:

`openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_0a6446eb3ae3_key -iv $encrypted_0a6446eb3ae3_iv -in super_secret.txt.enc -out super_secret.txt -d`

You can copy it to your `.travis.yml` file as I did [here](https://github.com/amadeu01/Rapadura/blob/master/.travis.yml#L39)

Do not forget to put your `.enc` file on your GitHub repository.

If you have multiple files, you could zip them and then you unzip the decrypted file on the Travis ci.

For instance, you can do like this:

```
$ tar cvf secrets.tar foo bar
$ travis encrypt-file secrets.tar
$ vi .travis.yml
$ git add secrets.tar.enc .travis.yml
$ git commit -m 'use secret archive'
$ git push
```

I did it.

In my case, I had two files to use on the build of my app. So, I used [this](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/#Encrypting-multiple-files) due to travis does not support multiple encrypted files. Therefore, you zip then on one file and encrypt this file.

You can have a look at my travis script [here](https://github.com/amadeu01/Rapadura/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Documentation says:

"For open source projects, we generally do not recommend including the app's Firebase config file or object in source control because, in most cases, your users should create their own Firebase projects and point their apps to their own Firebase resources (via their own Firebase config file or object)."

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more?authuser=0#config-files-objects

Answer (score 1):

Firebase documentation seems to imply that there is no problem in committing the file to GitHub.

Here is an extract from [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0#add-config-file)

> The Firebase config file contains unique, but non-secret identifiers for your project. To learn more about this config file, [visit Understand Firebase Projects.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more?authuser=0#config-files-objects)