# Google Analytics & Product Flavors

Tags: google-analytics, android-productflavors

I used the answer provided here:
[google-services.json for different productFlavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors)  to add a google-services.json files to my app/src/dev flavor folder and one to my app/src/production flavor folder. My dev debug variant will generate Events in my dashboard but my production release variant does not. The tracking_id is correct so not sure what I am missing.

- *I DO see a real Time Event for productionDebug variant, but why not productionRelease?
- Also I have an res/xml/app_tracker.xml  in each of my flavor folders
  with each having its respective correct ga_trackingId

Here is my google-services-json file for my production flavor:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_id": "shopper-64392",
    "project_number": "475366498847",
    "name": "Shopper"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:475366498847:android:847eba250b1fe1a7",
        "client_id": "android:ts.kiosk.app.shoppers",
        "client_type": 1,
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "ts.kiosk.app.shoppers",
          "certificate_hash": []
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "analytics_property": {
            "tracking_id": "UA-76684740-1"
          }
        },
        "cloud_messaging_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "apns_config": []
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "google_signin_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "client_info": [],
  "ARTIFACT_VERSION": "1"
}
```

Comment: No one has even a clue?