# Migrate Android app from GCM to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, migration, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to follow the instructions on migrating my app from GCM to the Firebase system, and according to [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#switch_to_fcm_in_the_app-level_buildgradle) link, I will have to download the new google-services.json file. However, I have already a previous google-services.json file that was generated when I enabled other APIs (including the GCM).

So my question is how am I supposed to include these two files in my app folder when they have the exact same name? Or am I supposed to paste the json code from the last file to my original one?

Please note that this is not about different [flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors), as both google-services.json files refer to the same app configuration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `google-services.json` file is be common across all the firebase components.

If you already downloaded the file from your firebase console then you are good. (every new download should return the same file, provided that you are using the same Firebase project)

If your previous file was generated before the firebase announce then it's worth to migrate your project and re download the file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Indeed, my project was created long before the firebase announce, where I already had a large json file that was generated when I activated APIs such as Google Analytics, GCM, etc. Now I migrated my project via my admob page, then downloaded the newly generated json file, which is much shorter than the previous one. I will replace the old with the new one, and come back to see if everything works and accept the answer.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to migrate to Firebase Cloud messaging, while leaving the rest of the services (analytics, admob etc) use GCM? As far as I understand, migrating would mean a complete migration of all services from GCM to Firebase, but I just want a confirmation.