# Firebase - Changing file name google-services.json?

Tags: android, firebase

Can I change the file name **google-services.json** to **prod-google-services.json**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the google service file name. You can use flavour to manage the google-services.json file.
Like this:

```
app/src/
flavor1/google-services.json
flavor2/google-services.json
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364376/1183691) for detail.

Also, very important to note : **You should not delete the google-services.json file from your app folder. Firebase will automatically use google-services.json file from flavor folder if it is present and neglect the google-services.json file from app folder.** [Thanks @KrishnaAgarwal]

Comment: thanks @captaindroid this works fine .Also, very important to note :
**You should not delete the google-services.json file from your app folder. Firebase will automatically use google-services.json file from flavor folder if it is present and neglect the google-services.json file from app folder.**

Comment: @KrishnaAgarwal Added the note in answer also.

Comment: How to select the flavour while using the app ?

Answer (score 2):

You *should **not*** change the name of the file if you intend to use it. If you're going to use different *google-services.json* file depending on the app environment, you should [Configure Product Flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors).

See [Firebase 2.0 - how to deal with multiple flavors (environments) of an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37463092/4625829)

Answer (score 1):

No you can not change file name . it was detected by android gradle while building project.