# How to use firebase push notification in single project multiple google-service.json in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have use single project but we want multiple files firebase push notification  google-server.json files how to maintain multiple file in android studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase 2.0 - how to deal with multiple flavors (environments) of an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463092/firebase-2-0-how-to-deal-with-multiple-flavors-environments-of-an-android-ap)

Comment: Hi Siva. I'm not sure how you'll get different google-services.json even though you only have *one project*, but have a look at the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37466889/4625829) in the possible duplicate post I linked.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible** because **google_services.json** file will working or download on bases of your project package name.

- i.e.when you implement **Google signUp** then download the JSON from
  google developer site.
- i.e.when you implement **Firebase** then download the JSON from
  google firebase console **by following steps** and overwrite extisting **google_service.json**.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create modules containing the **google-service.json**.
Then you can use interfaces to communicate the functionality withing the main app and modules.

e.g

### Structure

## app

build.gradle will contain

```
dependencies {
  compile project(":firebase-module-one")
  compile project(":firebase-module-two")
}
```

## firebase-module-one and firebase-module-two

build.gradle will contain

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
```

This module will contain the google-service.json