# Testing Googles Firebase Notifications on Development Device Only

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an android app where I want to be able to use the notification system within Firebase. I want to use the advanced features where I can add key/value pairs so that I can implement the notifications to do different things under certain conditions when clicked.

I obviously only want to test this on my test/development devices but can't see a way to do this.

Comment: When you say advanced features (key/value) pairs you refer to send the notification from your own server implementation? or what exactly do you need?

Comment: @GeorgeLBA No under the firebase console menu there is Notifications. From there you can enter a message and when to deliver, then you can expand Advanced and provide custom data in key/value pair format, it also includes other stuff such as expiry and priority etc

Comment: This is full totorial Sending Push Notifications to Android with Firebase https://www.codementor.io/android/tutorial/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new product flavor for your app (e.g. "development") ([Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)) and create a seperate firebase project (with a seperate google-services.json file) ([Add multiple google-services.json files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364376/2633917)).

Then you have different API keys for each project which don't effect each other.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, got tied up with something else. This did the trick, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You should choose **single device** choice on  "send notification" screen.
[image]

After that you should get your FCM registration token. Yo can get token via this app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tune.mytunedevice

Write your token and send notification.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the FCM registration ID for those testing devices and send the message just for them, or create a topic/testing and register those devices to that topic then send the message just for this topic.

Comment: How can I get the ID?

Comment: When the device is registered it will generate an ID you can get it programmatically send it to the firebase database...