# Gcm for debug build on Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to register different build variant of my app (release and debug) on GCM (it seems to me, I have migrate to Firebase Messaging, but I think the solution is the same)?
When I registered my app, I get a google-service.json, and a server-key. I sent the server key to backend developers, and included the json in my project.
Should I generate another json for debug build with project name "com.example.myapp.debug" (if my release build "com.example.myapp") and send this server key to backend devs too?
Is this is the solution, I still don't know where to put the json for different builds.
And my other question, what about GcmReceiver. I added

```
<action android:name="com.exmple.myapp />
```

should I replace this with

```
<action android:name="${applicationId}" />
```

Comment: Were you able to try out configuring build variants as per my answer? Or were you aiming for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest for you to create and use two separate projects for debug and release version, in order to avoid getting a *mix-up* when sending messages (i.e. accidental push to live devices while testing).

Not directly related, but the stated description mentioned in the [GCM CCS docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#connecting) gives you an idea of what I'm trying to say.

However, on a totally **related** note, as per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39100473/4625829):

> You could create a new product flavor for your app (e.g. "development") ([Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)) and create a seperate firebase project (with a seperate google-services.json file) ([Add multiple google-services.json files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364376/2633917)).
>
> Then you have different API keys for each project which don't effect each other.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create different google-service.json files. Add your main package name and create one. it will work both build and release version

Comment: Thanks, it works now on all of my build, I'd like to separate them.
Now I send debug messages to a debug channel, and release messages to news chanell, but I'd like to send all messages to news channel but with different server.