# FCM separate config file for staging and prod

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am using FCM for push notifications in my applications. There is a staging and a production server URL.

Do I need to generate two separate `google_services.json` files for staging and production?

Is it possible/recommended to modify values in the config file?

EDIT:

```
"project_info": {

"project_number": "xxxxxx",

"firebase_url": "https://stagingUrl",

"project_id": "xxxxxx",

"storage_bucket": "staging url.com"

}
```

My concern is that for the production server, the URL will also change. So will I need a separate file for this case?

Comment: why you want to seperate it for staging and live?

Comment: @LalitPoptani want to know whether it should be separate or not? Will the same config file work for both staging and live?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30772201/4625829), it might help.

Comment: @vishnus it depends on your requirement!

Comment: @AL. Thank you.. reading the answers.

Comment: @LalitPoptani - I have added code from the google_services.json to the question. Could you tell me whether i need two files or one file now?

Comment: If you are using one firebase project for staging and another for production then you would use two config files like @AL suggested. However if you are using the same project for both staging and production then you can use the same google-services.json file.

Comment: @ArthurThompson - Thank you. I was not aware that the server URL does not matter and is not defined in the config file.