# How to maintain multiple google-service.json in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, firebase, google-analytics

I was using `Google Analytics` which had a `google-services.json` file. But now I have added `Firebase`(not analytics service) which has another `google-services.json`.

I have checked both JSON files, `client` is a JSON array so I can add item to old `google-services.json` but both file has `project_info` JSON object which is different.

How can I merge these to file into one file? Or is it possible to point two files differently for two google services?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google-services.json for different productFlavors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors)

Comment: Did you solve this problem?