# Can one app be registered with different accounts in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase Messaging in my app and its registerd with one account in Firebase, now I have to use Firebase Analytics but I have to use another Firebase account for that. So is it possible to have same app registered for different Firebase features with different accounts?

Comment: did you try to do it ?

Comment: no it is not possible. you can add firebase dependencies only from one account. Similar Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698927/two-google-services-json-with-different-accounts-in-one-app

Comment: I don't think so, especially on the client side, you probably can mention only 1 api-key