# Use multiple google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist files in one flavor/target

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to use two google-services.json files in an Android project? I know that there is a possibility to use multiple google-services.json files for multiple flavors, but is it possible to somehow merge two files with different `project_info` and use them simultaneously for a project?

Below is the example of two files which I want to use in one project and one flavor (one for Analytics and another one for Ads).

First `google-services.json`

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "project_id": "project-one"
  },
  "client": [
    (...)
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Second `google-services.json`

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "YYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "firebase_url": "https://project-two.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "project-two",
    "storage_bucket": "project-two.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    (...)
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Also I have the same question regarding `GoogleService-Info.plist` files for an iOS project.

Comment: Have you read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors)?

Comment: Why project number and project id have different values for the same project?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes. But as I have written I want to use multiple google-services.json files in ONE flavor.

Comment: @AlexTa Because different parties are managing Analytics and Firebase Ads for the app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible to use more than one `FirebaseApp`. But you have to use the `FirebaseApp` configuration by code for the second configuration. `google-services.json` & `GoogleService-Info.plist` use to crate default FirebaseApp. For the second configuration use `class func configure(name: String, options: FIROptions)`(Swift) & `public static FirebaseApp initializeApp (Context context, FirebaseOptions options, String name)`(Android).

iOS demo code:-

```
   let options =  FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:ios:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", gcmSenderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
   options.apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
   options.projectID = "App-XXXXX"
   FirebaseApp.configure(name: "AppAnalytics", options: options)
```

Add `FirebaseOptions` data/values from `google-services.json` & `GoogleService-Info.plist` files.

Please refer to the below link for more details:

iOS:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FirebaseApp
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FirebaseOptions

Android:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp#initializeApp(android.content.Context,%20com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: What about for the Flutter packages? That's what I'm looking for, actually. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @GustavoLopes Yes, Check out this doc: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core/latest/firebase_core/Firebase/initializeApp.html (Use `FirebaseOptions` and name) https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core_platform_interface/latest/firebase_core_platform_interface/FirebaseOptions-class.html

Comment: That is perfect!! In the end, the problem was with the flutter library. But your solution made me realize that and I could fork and update the library to my needs. Thank you. You were really helpful!