# Obtain google-services.json externally

Tags: android, json, firebase, service

I have an Android app that receives push notifications sent via Firebase. My project includes the google-services.json generated from Firebase with my account.

I would like to know if there's a way to avoid putting the google-services.json inside the project and obtain this info externally, from a server of mine for example, once the APK is built and installed in the device.

The main goal is to be able to choose which Firebase account the app uses from my server web app.

Thanks!

Comment: google-services.json for different productFlavors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors

Comment: Thanks @eurosecom!!

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no such option. The whole point is to bind your app with one Google Service doing the same thing (like push notifications). You can use multiple files/services for different things though - i.e. one for real time database and another for push notification.