# Android: How to load different google-services.json file if in debug mode?

Tags: android

I have 2 different google-services.json files, one for my development DB, and the other for my production DB.

How would I make Android load the development one in dev mode, and production one in release mode?

Comment: given i can use that, where would i actually specify which google-services.json file to load though?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google-services.json for different productFlavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors)