# Support for multiple google-services.json in Flavor based Android Approach

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-build-flavors

I have an android app with four flavours.Each flavor has his its own google-services.json file.

This file needs to be under /app structure.I found this approach to be working in various links:

```
productFlavors{
        one{
            applicationId 'com.flavor.one'
            versionName '2.4.3'
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 26
            copy {
                from 'src/one/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }
 }
        two{
            applicationId 'com.flavor.two'
            versionName '1.0.13'
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23

            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 26
           copy {
                from 'src/two/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }

        }
        three{
            applicationId 'com.flavor.three'
            versionName '1.4.1'
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23

            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 5
       copy {
                from 'src/three/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }

        }
        four{
            applicationId 'com.flavor.four'
            versionName '1.4.1'
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23

            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 5



        }
    }
```

But this approach is always copying the last json to app directory.Not copying the flavor based json.

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors?rq=1

Comment: already seen this link.