# Different flavours for 3 different firebase projects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-flavors

I am having 3 different domains,
A,B and C.

I have created 3 different Firebase projects in their individual respective consoles.

My Question

I am planning to create a single Android project and add flavours to them to support A,B,C and also place their respective google-json files in the respective flavour directory.

Remember that I cannot combine A,B,C in a single firebase project as those are totally 3 different domains.

I wondering if creating a product flavor will suit my requirement or not ?

How can I achieve it via flavors ? If not the only possible way is to create 3 different projects ?

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors. You should place file `google-services.json` for each build variant (combination of flavor dementions and build type). I think it may be automated with custom gradle task.

Comment: Yes, It's possible. In my case, I'm having 2 flavors for each Google Analytics. I put xml file to each resource folder of the product flavor.

Comment: i have same issue, please tell me if you get proper solution
Please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58961183/8740243