# Use different google-service.json for testing in Android

Tags: android, firebase, testing

I am building an Android application using Firebase. Thus, I have a `google-services.json` file in my root `app` directory. I'd like to tell Android to use a different `google-services.json` file when running tests, but I'm not sure how to do this. I don't want to run tests against the production database. Can anyone provide a step-by-step guide on how to configure product flavors or something to use a different `google-services.json` according to whether or not I am testing?

Answer (score 3):

Let us say you have different product flavors and corresponding Firebase applications in the firebase console project. You could get the google-services.json for each application and add them in your respective flavor directory in your application.

For example :

```
app/src/
beta/google-services.json
alpha/google-services.json
production/google-services.json
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors) here explains in detail how you could manage buildTypes along with flavors and further.