# Gradle Warnings: Could not find google-services.json while looking in

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, android-flavors

I got the following warnings.
How can I avoid this warnings?

> Could not find google-services.json while looking in
>   [src/flavor1/debug, src/debug, src/flavor1] Could not find
>   google-services.json while looking in [src/flavor1/release,
>   src/release, src/flavor1] Could not find google-services.json while
>   looking in [src/flavor2/debug, src/debug, src/flavor2] Could not find
>   google-services.json while looking in [src/flavor2/release,
>   src/release, src/flavor2]

---

I added two client_info at **app/google-services.json**

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "000000000000",
    "project_id": "****-*****"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": ...,
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "flavor1.package.name"
        }
      },
      ...
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": ...,
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "flavor2.package.name"
        }
      },
      ...
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Comment: @Dhaust This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors?noredirect=1&lq=1

This only concerns the warnings and not that the file is missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per my experience, this will occur when you are using any  type of service related to firebase and you have not put the `google-services.json` the file which we needed to use the service,

The solution is you need to get the file from firebase console and you need to put inside of your app level folder if you are creating a single project in the console for all flavor and If you are creating different one then you need to create a number of files for a number of projects or flavors.

Comment: I have this file in the "/app/" folder, yet it doesn't find it. Instead it keeps showing me this in the build log: `Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)`

Comment: @androiddeveloper, using the latest google-services version (4.1.0 as of this writing) seems to fix it.

Comment: This was an issue in google dependency and it's fixed now in  com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2

Comment: @ozbek .. your answer work for me..

Answer (score 6):

> Could not find google-services.json while looking in

According to **LOGCAT**, **`google-services.json`** is absent in right place (Missing).

The **`google-services.json`** file is generally placed in the **`app/ directory (at the root of the Android Studio app module).`**

- Read official guideline about [**`Adding the JSON`**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

For example, dogfood and release are build types.

```
 app/
    google-services.json
    src/dogfood/google-services.json
    src/release/google-services.json
    ...
```

Finally, **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Comment: I already place google-services.json file in the app/ directory. I just want to hide that warnings.

Comment: @DrumRobot read https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin . Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have two flavors with different pakage names, but I put two `client_info` in one **google-services.json** file in the **app/** directory

Comment: @DrumRobot Sometimes little mistake costing us.

Comment: @DrumRobot I am seeing the same issue. Even with a google-services.json generated by the Firebase plugin in Android Studio that contains all flavors in a single app/google-services.json. It is something that should be fixed in the google-services-plugin.

Comment: This was an issue in google dependency and its fixed now in com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2

Comment: @M.Noman ok. I will updated my answer.

Comment: I can confirm that updating to google-services:4.0.2 fixed the issue for me.