# "no matching client found for package name" with build flavors and the correct package hierarchy

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am having this weird problem with my build: I have a build flavor with a certain app id, and I'm defining the correct package that matches it, my folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
+ src
++ flavor1
+++ google-services.json
++ flavor2
+++ google-services.json
```

the reference in google-services.json have the correct package name as well, and I'm still getting this error that "no matching client found for package name" only for the flavor2 package, flavor1 works fine.

I've been stuck with this for more than a day now, tried everything from clean/rebuild, recreate the hierarchy, clear the cache, nothing did the trick. Any idea what's going wrong or what else to try?

Comment: don't understand which one is not working? you said flavor1 and flavor2 is working

Answer (score 0):

Google included support for flavors in version 2.0 of the play services plugin. Since this version of the `gradle plugin com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3`

you can do this

```
app/src/
    flavor1/google-services.json
    flavor2/google-services.json
```

Version 3.0.0 of the plugin will search for the json file in these locations (considering you have a `flavor` flavor1 and a build type `debug`):

```
/app/src/flavor1/google-services.json
/app/src/flavor1/debug/google-services.json
/app/src/debug/google-services.json
/app/src/debug/flavor1/google-services.json
/app/google-services.json
```

This worked for me even using flavorDimensions. I have free & paid in one dimension and Mock & Prod in the other dimension. I also have 3 buildTypes: debug, release and staging. This is how it looks in my project for the FreeProd flavor:

[image]

How many google-services.json files will depend on your project's characteristics, but you will need at least one json file for every Google  project.

If you want more details about what this plugin does with these json files, here it is:
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54#issuecomment-165824720

Link to the official docs:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

And go here to check the latest version of this plugin: https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/view

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364376/6891563)