# google-services.json issue with debug variant

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to test my app that is now converted from GCM to FCM.  If the build variant is release the app runs.  But when I changed the varient to debug and ran the app.  I got . . .

"No matching client found for package name 'com.deanblakely.myapp.debug'"

After poking around I think it may have something to do with the google-services.json that I got from the Firebase console but I'm not sure.  All the posts I found on the subject were like 3 years old.

Comment: Although this answer is from 2016, I think it is still valid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38479169/4815718. Also, look at [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html), especially the section titled "Small team, simple app".

Comment: Bob: That blog post cleared whole flavor and variant issue.  Thanks