# Flavors error - No matching client found for package name

Tags: android, android-flavors

i try to implement flavors by this guide:
https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-1-building-white-label-apps-on-android-ade16af23bcf

but i get this error:

> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.client1'

this is my gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example'
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 19
    versionName '9.7'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    ashkelon {
        applicationIdSuffix ".client1"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

and this is the source tree:

```
src/
    main/
    client1/
```

any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors

Comment: I can not find a solution to my problem there. you can guide me a little more?

Comment: Did you put your `google-services.json` corresponding to your flavor inside `src/client1/` ?

Comment: now i did and it's work well. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

It means you have only one google-services.json

you need to add one more google-services.json file for **client1**