# Is it possible to connect my android app to multiple firebasedatabase project?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I am new in `FirebaseDatabase` stuff.
I need to firebase project to be connected with one app.

I actually need one firebase project more secured, and other one that everyone can read and write!

is it possible?

Comment: If its for development purpose that you want to use different databases for different environment you can define separate Flavours in gradle file .

Comment: @ADM, 
How can i do that?
can you explain please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors