# Multiple Builds Environment in Flutter for Firebase Using buildTypes (multiple google-services.json)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I created multiple firebase project in one app to separate the development and production environment, so now I have 2 different generated google-services.json. I want to be able to run/build using a specific environment by specifying buildTypes as mentioned in [this article on step 3](https://www.tengio.com/blog/multiple-firebase-environments-with-flutter/). So my app folder below will follow this article.

NOTE: Why don't I use flavor? Because I already use command arguments (--dart-define).

This is snippet of my buildTypes:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

I delete `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as stated in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects).

This is my app folder:

[image: Folder structure]

I run my project using debug build (`flutter run --debug`) but I got this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "google-services.json" file to the project?
```

I checked [this documentation page](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/core/usage/) on firebase flutter site, it mentioned:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'SecondaryApp',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
        appId: 'my_appId',
        apiKey: 'my_apiKey',
        messagingSenderId: 'my_messagingSenderId',
        projectId: 'my_projectId'
    )
);
```

is my choice only passing all required data via command arguments using this approach? I'm afraid it has limitations as I use other Firebase services. Any insights would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way, this works for me:

1. Add this code in your android/app build.gradle:

   ```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           shrinkResources true
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           debuggable false
           copy {
               from 'src/main'
               include 'google-services.json'
               into '.'
           }
       }

       debug {
           applicationIdSuffix ".debug" //Change this according to your requirement
           debuggable true
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           copy {
               from 'src/debug'
               include 'google-services.json'
               into '.'
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Next, add the google-services.json like this:

[image]

Add them inside android/app/src and then respective folders.

3. Finally, run the app in debug or release mode to automatically update

Comment: this is by far the most straightforward way and worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your google-services.json file is under the incorrect folder. It should be in android/app. Not android/app/src/debug. You can follow [this official document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android/).

> Once your Android app has been registered, download the configuration file from the Firebase Console (the file is called google-services.json). Add this file into the android/app directory within your Flutter project.

Comment: I have 2 google-services.json files for different environments, I think I can't put it in same folder. But let's say I edit one google-services.json filename, how can I use specific google-services.json based on my buildType?

Comment: Ok, you can follow this instruction:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364376/10659482

Comment: Wow thanks for the nice thread, I'll test several approaches that suit my use case.