# google-services.json for different productFlavors and buildTypes

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, android-productflavors, android-build-type

My project has 2 flavor

-flavor1
-flavor2

and 3 buildTypes

-release
-uat
-dev

How Can I add google-service.json to my project?

And What will my project structure look like?

I use

> com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5

I saw many post but It use com.google.gms:google-services:3.x.x. I am not sure that is still valid answer

Answer (score 0):

In your project under the src directory create 3 folders and paste the different json files like this

release

```
    --google-service.json
```

uat

```
   -google-service.json
```

dev

```
   -google-service.json
```

runtime based on the build Types it will takes corresponding json

Comment: So the structure will be app/src/release/flavor1 app/src/release/flavor2 app/src/uat/flavor1 app/src/uat/flavor2 app/src/dev/flavor1 app/src/dev/flavor2 ,right?

Comment: refer this, hope it will have more clear info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors

Comment: @saikamar Thank for reference but the top answer use Version 3.0.0 of the plugin but I use 4.3.5