# Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am integrating **GCM** to a project using `Android Studio` for that I am adding google play service dependencies to `top level` gradle as below snippet code:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'  //this one
}
```

But I am getting error `Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0` and `Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0`. I have updated the goole play service from SDK manager and sync the project.

I have added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in top-level gradle also but its still showing same error

Comment: add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in project level gradle

Comment: I have done that also

Comment: and are you adding any play service library to your project ??

Comment: Can u try as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527369/error-could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services1-0-when-adding-google-ser

Comment: @Sree - nope i am trying to integrating google play service

Comment: @Raghavendra - the link you have given is for different issue its not the same issue.

Comment: i have the same issue, better you download lay service library and add as a module then set references, NOTE : do't forgot to build gradle for play service library. and add in your gradle file, it will work

Comment: @Sree - that is what i am asking what should i have to add in gradle??? I have tried to use `compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0` but wouldn't help me out

Comment: Do you know how to add a dependency in android Studio ?

Comment: @Sree- What you think ??

Comment: Really i am sorry, i dot know what is your problem, I had the same issue, i resolved it by adding play services library as module in to my project and set that as dependency

Comment: and do your updated classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'  with    *'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0''*

Comment: Google official document showing `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'` you can check [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Comment: com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0 is out that i am sure

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to reference the full google play services just add the GCM reference to the build.gradel module.

this is what mine looks like and works fine.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
}
```

then make sure you run the build.grade. the version may have also changed since i added mine.

Also note you are putting it into the wrong gradel file, use the module not the top one

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have *latest* `Android Studio` installed, along with *updated* `Google Play Services`. It can also be a cause of error mentioned. Moreover, you don't need to add plugin line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as well. It will compile fine without it. Currently, I am using **Android Studio 2.1** and **gradle version 2.10** to compile following gradle configuration.

**Build.gradle (Project Level)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build.gradle (app Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.package.id.here"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
   }
```