# Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, build.gradle, newrelic

Anytime I try to build my project I keep getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
No matching client found for package name 'com.my.package'
```

I have made and remade the `google-services.json` and have used the app and the package `com.my.package`.

Here's my project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    ...
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
    classpath 'com.github.JakeWharton:sdk-manager-plugin:220bf7a88a7072df3ed16dc8466fb144f2817070'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:4.265.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha9'
  }
}
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
  }
}
// Define versions in a single place
ext {
  supportLibraryVersion = '23.2.0'
  playServicesVersion = '8.4.0'
}
```

Here's my app build.gradle:

```
  apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
  apply plugin: 'newrelic'
  apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

  android {
    packagingOptions {
      exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
      exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    dexOptions {
      jumboMode true
    }

    lintOptions {
      disable 'InvalidPackage'
      abortOnError false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.my.package"
      minSdkVersion 15
      targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
      debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
        ...
      }

      staging {
        applicationIdSuffix '.staging'
        versionNameSuffix '-STAGING'
        ...
      }

      release {
        ...
      }
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion",
            "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion",
            "com.android.support:percent:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion",
            "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion",
            "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion",
            "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$rootProject.playServicesVersion",
            "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:$rootProject.playServicesVersion",
            "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$rootProject.playServicesVersion",
            "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$rootProject.playServicesVersion",
            ...
            'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.265.0',
            'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
  }

  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) several times. I am also using my release configuration so there isn't any reason the applicationIdSuffix should be an issue. Also, com.my.pacakage is just a stand-in for my pacakge name. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually with NewRelic not with my configuration. I removed it and followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32083671/1167780) as I was using BuildTypes. Now it compiles as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by NewRelic ?

Answer (score 11):

You need to provide `google-services.json` for all **flavors** (release and development etc)

Single `google-services.json` can have json/data for all flavors. Go to Google Developers Console and regenerate `google-services.json` file

**Update**

You can also create separate `google-services.json` files for flavors

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Answer (score 4):

Google just included support for **flavors on version 2.0** of the play services plugin. Since this version of the gradle plugin `com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha9`

you can do this

[image]

For More details please go through below link.
If you want more details about what this plugin does with these json files, [here it is](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54#issuecomment-165824720):

[Link to the official docs:](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

And go here to check the latest version of [this plugin](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/view):

[Ref link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527369/error-could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services1-0-when-adding-google-ser)

Answer (score 3):

In my case it solved my problem

```
      ...  
 "client": [
        {
          "client_info": {
            "mobilesdk_app_id": "yourid",
            "android_client_info": {
              "package_name": "ru.example.app"
            }
          },
       ...
```

package_name should be same as in applicationId

```
        defaultConfig {
                applicationId "ru.example.app"
                minSdkVersion 15
                targetSdkVersion 23
                ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late but I had a similar problem.

It occurred when I initially connected my app to Firebase analytics for some reason it only picked up my "debug" flavor.

I had to log into Firebase, go to the console and select the relevant project and then manually add the additional "release" flavor.

Then I reconnected to Firebase in Android Studio (which automatically updated and downloaded the json file from Firebase into Studio), re-compiled my app and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue and realised it was because I had renamed my app and changed my bundleid but had not rerun

```
flutterfire configure
```

as I am using Firebase cloud storage. Reconfiguring the app recreated the google-services.json file and fixed my issue so I could then rerun:

```
flutter build appbundle
```