# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name com.xxx.xxx

Tags: android

I get and error when I try to Sync project with Gradles files

Here is the error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   No matching client found for package name 'ua.com.qascript.android'

And here is the Gradle file content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
    packagingOptions {

        exclude('META-INF/NOTICE')
    }
    packagingOptions {

        exclude('META-INF/LICENSE')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ua.com.qascript.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionName '1.7'
        versionCode 11
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
}
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Well, this error appear after I update the Google Play Services to can add Firebase Cloud Messages, it request minimum vers 9.0.

Please help me to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: This link provides you solution[LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35894567/3779239)