# package name change but not working in gradle

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

```
package com.abhimathgame.shubham.mindsharp;
```

In build.gradle in manually change the package name

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abhimathgame.shubham.mindsharp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

And after that i sync the gradle but it return error and whrn is use

```
applicationId "com.example.shubham.mindsharp"
```

it ok but not publish on Playstore [Error Image for more help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6IoQ.png)

Comment: Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: Can you please let me know which Build Variant your using? Below Side Tab on your left-hand side.

Comment: Can you recheck "package" attribute on Android Manifest file?

Comment: just changing in build.gradle, will not work. What I did was searched for old package name(this will be generally used in Java Class, Manifest and/or Strings.xml), just replace every place you find the old package name.

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abhimathgame.shubham.mindsharp">

Comment: Build Variant using 3.0.1 @Chinmay

Comment: No,  Not that you are running your project in debug mode or release mode. Check for flavors in Build Varient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first of all to update google service to the most recent version.
Also do you use [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)?

Also could be that you re using New Relic as indicated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876643/execution-failed-for-task-appprocessreleasegoogleservices-no-matching-cli/35894567#35894567)? It is referring to this [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/automatic-per-variant-google-services-json-configurations-with-gradle-d3d3e40abc0e) where is explained exactly the nature of the issue:

> the google_services.json must reside in the root of your :app module
>   and not within a buildType/productVariant folder, so Gradle cannot
>   handle this automatically for you via folder placement.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your package name is same at all the places. Also if you have added google-services.json file from firebase in your project make sure the packagename added there is correct.
Hope this is helpful.