# com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 11 column 10 path $.client[0].client_info

Tags: flutter, release

So I added FCM and it works but if I want to run the command  `flutter buil apk --release`  I get the foolowing error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 11 column 10 path $.client[0].client_info.<<<<<<<

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      12.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I found this SO  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876643/execution-failed-for-task-appprocessreleasegoogleservices-no-matching-cli) but if I delete the line with `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` the push notifications doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your *google-services.json* file. Did you edit it manually by chance? You can try downloading the file again from Firebase or try to find the missing ':'. It should be near the top of the file (line 10-11). Find the "client" key, then the first "client_info" key.

Comment: I already have this line.. The thing is if I delete apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' the app runs but I don't receive push notifications anymore

Comment: I resolved this already like yday I think but
Yeah it was with the json.. It wasn't formatted correctly

Answer (score 1):

check your `google-services.json` file anything will be wrong.