# Error Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not foun with latest classpath

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services

I know it has been asked a lot of times here but no matter how much answers I search It keeps happenning ever since I updated android studio to the new stable version.

I've updated every single SDK Tool and confirmed that Google Play Services is installed. I've even tested with classpath 3.0.0 and 3.1.0 and lot of firebase compile versions but still happens and I don't know what more to do.

***Update:***

I got this error after updating gradle to v3 and then reversing it to 2.3.3 becasue some compatibility issues

I've noticed that some people report that the same error tells them that It has tried looking for the plugin in some repositories, but mine just doesn't
[image]

Here is my build config:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven' }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the Project one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appsr.appname"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 122
        versionName "2.2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'

    //Preferences
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.4.0.0' //Bugfix preference library

    //HttpClient
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v1.0.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'

    //Serialize classes in JSON
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    //Others
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527369/error-could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services1-0-when-adding-google-ser

Comment: @SagarJethva I've done everything told in this post but still happens. The weird stuff is that my error does not show like it has tried to search it in any repository

Comment: Should try this adding in your project level build.gradle `buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter();
        mavenCentral()
    }`

Comment: @SagarJethva Yes, It gives the same results

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by Restarting Android Studio, seems like a weird bug of the IDE that happens when changing some Gradle properties